# Do all Windows containers have the same DPAPI machine key?

Tags: windows, docker

Is the DPAPI machine key for all Windows machines the same for all Docker containers? At least for each base image? Is it generated magically somehow when the container is started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows containers now generate a DP API key when the container is first  started.[1]

[1] https://www.impidio.com/blog/dp-api-encryption-ineffective-in-windows-containers